# Base Class Pointer doesn't see members of Derived

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Here is my code.  I don't understand why I don't reach with `b->x`;

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Nesne.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Derived obj;
    Base *b=&obj;

    b->a=2;
    b->x=3;


    return 0;
}
```

Nesne.h

```
#ifndef NESNE_H
#define NESNE_H


class Base
{
   public:
    int a;

    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
protected:
private:
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
int x;
  Derived(){};
};

#endif // NESNE_H
```

Comment: I add image , you can easily look

Comment: Don't post *screenshots of text*. Stack Overflow lets you actually enter text into the question.

Comment: Why should you reach it? There's no `Base::x`.

Comment: Please no screenshots of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance goes in the other direction.

A pointer to a Derived object can see Base members, but a pointer to Base cannot see Derived members.  There is no `virtual` for data members, and even for functions it would be virtual only if declared so in Base.  (virtual lets you access a Derived version of a function through a Base pointer or reference).

Since the member you want is there, even though it can't be accessed that way, you could use `static_cast` to access it:

```
static_cast<Derived*>(b)->x = 3;
```

Comment: You mean a reinterpret_cast<> ? static_cast<> will work here too, but reinterpret_cast<> veryfies that the desired cast is in the inheritance chain. If not the cast becomes a nullptr. static_cast<> does not do this check and will always return a pointer, valid or invalid,

Comment: @Viktor Lier No I certainly did not mean `reinterpret_cast` and neither should you.  `reinterpret_cast` would be seriously wrong.  You meant `dynamic_cast` and I still disagree.  The choice between `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` can be a judgment call.  But your general rejection of `static_cast` is not good software engineering.

Comment: Actually, ı will use vector like vector<Base*> vec; But ı dont understand here

Comment: @JSF: Right, I really meant `dynamic_cast` not `reinterpret_cast`. When did I talk about a general rejection of `static_cast`?

Comment: The objection to `static_cast` in your comment only makes sense as a general rejection of `static_cast` to derived class.  In the example we are talking about, there is no question the runtime type is correct for the `static_cast`.  So if you don't like `static_cast` to derived here, where would you like it?  Ordinary code is filled with such situations in which a pointer to base class is known to be valid for a static cast to derived.  A `dynamic_cast` is almost always just a start.  Then you need a test for NULL and an alternate execution path.  Most often there is no plausible alternate.